# SQL - How to limit data entry of one attribute depending on another attribute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ddl

Below is the DDL for the table I want to create. However, I want the attribute 'Expertise_breed' to be derived from 'Expertise_animal'. For example, if 'Dog' is entered into 'Expertise_animal' I don't want to be able to enter in a breed of cat. How would I go about achieving this?
I'm working with SQL Server Management Studio 2012

```
CREATE TABLE tExpertise
(
Expertise_ID        int         NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY, --E.G Data '001'
Expertise_type      varchar(8)  NOT NULL,              --E.G Data 'Domestic'
Expertise_animal    varchar(30) NOT NULL,              --E.G Data 'Dog'
Expertise_breed     varchar(30) NOT NULL               --E.G Data 'Poodle'
)
```

Comment: And how do you want to teach your SQL Server that `Poodle` is indeed a `dog`?

Comment: You can create check constraint

Comment: That check constraint would look like a small database.

Comment: How about adding a check constraint like `CONSTRAINT AK_tExpertise_unique UNIQUE(Expertise_type, Expertise_animal, Expertise_breed) `? But the question remains: how do you want to teach an SQL Server that a `bat` is not a `bird`? Either you hard-code it. But then you might as well pre-fill the list with all possible / admissible combinations or a person will have to verify the new entries and you simply add a `IsVerified` bit to the end of the table and ask users to validate the data.

Comment: It depends on how complicated is your constraint. Generally, use check-constrain if it is simple. if it is complicated you need to use trigger.

Answer (score 2):

This is a relation data situation, you should use relational tables.

I would have three
AnimalClassification - (domestic,wild,other)
AnimalSpecies (dog,cat,goat)
AnimalBreed (Poodle, Beagle)
Animal species would have a foreign key to animal classification i.e.
Dog - domestic
Animal breed would have a foreign key to animal species i.e.
Beagle - dog

Answer (score -1):

You can create a trigger on insert and/or update and compare those two columns for each row. You can refer to the inserted entries via 'inserted' alias.

If you know what mappings are allowed (eg dog x poodle) you could store it in some table and join to it in the insert to filter out the wrong ones.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically, what you want can be achieved using table level [constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187550.aspx#Check), a generic way of doing this being the following (*not tested*):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.validateExpertise(
    @expertise_type varchar(8),
    @Expertise_animal varchar(30),
    @Expertise_breed varchar(30)   
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@Expertise_animal == 'dog' AND @Expertise_breed != 'dog') 
        RETURN 0;

    -- other validations can come here

    RETURN 1;
END
GO

-- add a table level constraint
-- WITH NOCHECK can be used to not check existing data
ALTER TABLE detailTable ADD CONSTRAINT chkExpertise
        CHECK (dbo.validateExpertise(expertise_type, Expertise_animal, Expertise_breed) = 1)
```

While this may help you, it is not recommended to put such complex validation at database level. Complex validations are meant to be (at least) implemented in the business layer of your application, which is typically within the [Logic tier](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Overview_of_a_three-tier_application_vectorVersion.svg/2000px-Overview_of_a_three-tier_application_vectorVersion.svg.png) (usually ASP.NET MVC, WCF service, Web service etc.) (some validations are also put in the presentation layer to avoid round-trips time delays.

Database is meant primarily for data persistence and fetch. Of course, simple constraints such as `FK`s, `unique` constraints, column level constraints etc. are welcomed, as they act as a good safety net.

Also, keep in mind that constraints like the one mentioned above will trigger for every `INSERT` or `UPDATE` in the table and might seriously degrade the performance for queries involving a large number of records.